# Using a regex to replace characters in a string in an Angular template

Tags: javascript, angular

I know that I can normally use `myString.replace(/\*/g, '')` to remove `*` from a string.  But I cannot seem to make that work in a Angular HTML template.  Here is what I doing ...

```
<div class="panel panel--raised">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group__text">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search... (min of 3 characters)" [(ngModel)]="searchString" minlength="3">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <button class="btn btn--success btn--small host-info-button"
              [disabled]="searchString.replace(/\*/g, '').length < 3"
              (click)="getInfo(searchString)">Search</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`Parser Error: Unexpected token / ...`

What am I doing wrong here?

Update:

What I am trying to do is make the user enter at least 3 characters that are not wildcard (`*`) characters.  So `a**` would only count as 1 character and `***` would count as zero characters, but `*xyz*` would count as 3 characters.  I am not sure that `Validator.pattern()` would be able to accomplish this, but maybe I am just lacking imagination.

Comment: This feels like a use case for a pattern validator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**in template:**

```
[disabled]="isDisabled"
```

**in ts file:**

```
get isDisabled(): boolean {
    return this.searchString.replace(/\*/g, '').length < 3;
}
```

Comment: Ah ... I was just lacking imagination.  Thanks this works great!

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, RegExp literal is not supported by the templating language. They should be on your component.

More info on Angular Github repo issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21978

For this particular case, you can set up pattern validator and use something like this: `Validators.pattern('/\*/g')`

Comment: ug! I want to be able to make the user enter at least 3 characters not counting *'s before they can submit a search.  Is there some sort of validation I should set up?

Comment: Edited the answer

Comment: Where do I put `Validators.pattern(...)` in my code?

Comment: Please refer to this documentation: https://angular.io/api/forms/PatternValidator